# App icon disappear when uninstalling another app in Android

Tags: android

I installed two similar apps, they are the apps with different package name. When I uninstall one of them, the launcher icon of the other one disappears too. But The app can still be found in settings->all apps. And the icon appears after rebooting device. The problem only happens on some devices. Why does this problem happen? Thanks!

Comment: Please do mention the devices on which it works and those where you encounter the problem.